# Azure DevOps VSTS.AccountContents for PowerBI issue

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

I am using PowerBI M Query function "VSTS.AccountContents" to build a dashboard on Azure DevOps buils and releases.
Function docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-functions?view=azure-devops

To be able refresh the dataset once published in Power BI Service I need to use the "options" argument named "Query"..
Unfortunately, the query parameter seem to be ignored.

This code works but doesn't allow refresh

```
(ContinuationToken as number) =>
let
    response = VSTS.AccountContents("https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/xxxxx/xxx/_apis/release/deployments?api-version=6.0"
        & "&"
        & "latestAttemptsOnly=true&"
        & "queryOrder=descending&"
        & "$top=100&"
        & "continuationToken=" & Number.ToText(ContinuationToken))

in
    response
```

This code allows refresh in Power BI Service but doesn't return the requested rows

```
(ContinuationToken as number) =>
let
        response = VSTS.Contents("https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/xxxxx/xxx/_apis/release/deployments?api-version=6.0",
        [Query=[q="api-version=6.0&latestAttemptsOnly=true&queryOrder=descending&$top=100&continuationToken=" & Number.ToText(ContinuationToken)]]
    )

in
    response
```

Has anyone been able to make this work?

Thank you